# Sony Vaio VPCP115 8" TrackPoint doesn't work on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

Just bought a Sony Vaio VPCP115 8" pocket laptop. 1.6G Atom CPU, 2G mem, 64G SSD.

Installation went smoothly. Network, video (Skype), and most of Ubuntu features work. TrackPoint isn't recognized by system and it doesn't respond either. Wondering how to configure TrackPoint.

Answer (score 0):

Configure video driver and trackball. Edit `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash mem=1900mb nohz=off i8042.reset i8042.nomux i8042.nopnp i8042.noloop"
```

Then run

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

I verified this solution that perfectly worked on my VPCP115 Sony Vaio pocket laptop. Wonderful.

(Credits for the answer: http://vimalkumar.in/2010/08/16/ubuntu-10-04-on-the-sony-vaio-p/)